Learning from label proportions
Can someone please tell me how to implement this algorithm via this paper in simple Python as possible?
I asked for code from the author but got no reply after 7 months of retrying.
EDIT: Added code ( I´m not sure how the training input are. Should we only add label proportions or should we add labels in y?
How can we combine any learning algorithm to theirs? I´m not sure if I have combined this with logistic regression.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

# Define the neural network model for g
class SimpleNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.output = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.hidden(x))
        x = self.output(x)
        return x

# Corrected function g_hat using soft labels
def g_hat_soft(model, x, alpha, k):
    p = alpha
    x = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)  # Convert to tensor and add batch dimension
    pred = model(x).squeeze().item()  # Get prediction from the model
    return (k * (p - alpha) + alpha) * pred + (k * (alpha - p) + (1 - alpha)) * pred

# Generate surrogate labels
def generate_surrogate_labels(alpha, size):
    return np.random.binomial(1, alpha, size)

# Example data for training, reflecting collection S
S = [{'data': np.array([[2], [3], [4]]), 'alpha': 0 / 3},  
    {'data': np.array([[1], [2], [3]]), 'alpha': 1 / 3}, 
    {'data': np.array([[5], [1], [1]]), 'alpha': 2 / 3},
    {'data': np.array([[5], [2], [3]]), 'alpha': 0 / 3},
    {'data': np.array([[1], [1], [1]]), 'alpha': 3 / 3},  
    {'data': np.array([[2], [4], [5]]), 'alpha': 0 / 3},  
    {'data': np.array([[4], [2], [3]]), 'alpha': 0 / 3},  
    {'data': np.array([[1], [2], [1]]), 'alpha': 2 / 3},  
    {'data': np.array([[1], [1], [3]]), 'alpha': 2 / 3},  
    {'data': np.array([[1], [2], [1]]), 'alpha': 2 / 3},  
    {'data': np.array([[1], [4], [5]]), 'alpha': 1 / 3},  
     ]

# Hyperparameters
input_size = 1
hidden_size = 10
output_size = 1
learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 100
lambda_reg = 0.1  # Regularization parameter

# Initialize the neural network
model = SimpleNN(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=lambda_reg)  # L2 regularization

# Training process
for epoch in range(epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for bag in S:
        alpha = bag['alpha']
        x_samples = bag['data']
        k = len(x_samples)
        y_tilde_samples = generate_surrogate_labels(alpha, k)

        for idx in range(k):
            x_t = x_samples[idx]
            y_tilde_t = y_tilde_samples[idx]

            # Convert to tensors
            x_t_tensor = torch.tensor(x_t, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)
            y_tilde_t_tensor = torch.tensor([y_tilde_t], dtype=torch.float32)

            # Forward pass
            y_pred = model(x_t_tensor)

            # Compute the loss
            correction = g_hat_soft(model, x_t, alpha, k)
            loss = criterion(y_pred, y_tilde_t_tensor) + (y_pred - correction) ** 2

            # Backward pass and optimization
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # Accumulate loss
            total_loss = loss.item()

    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}, Loss: {total_loss}")

# Example data for testing (new samples)
test_samples = np.array([[1], [5], [3],[4]])
test_samples_tensor = torch.tensor(test_samples, dtype=torch.float32)

# Predict using the trained model
predictions = model(test_samples_tensor).detach().numpy()
predicted_labels = [1 if p >= 0.4 else 0 for p in predictions]

print("Predictions on test samples:", predictions)
print("Predicted labels on test samples:", predicted_labels)


What progress habe you made? Where are you stuck?

@picky_porpoise I have added a possible step with questions. I'm still very unsure if this is correct. I tried to read the paper many times but still can`t figure out things without a guide
